# Problemas ao adcionar números em um ArrayList

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

Meu código está assim:

```
public class QuestionarioController implements Initializable {

    InicioController inicio = new InicioController();
    Quiz questionario = new Quiz();

    @FXML
    private Label lblPergunta;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbQuestion1;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbQuestion2;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbQuestion3;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbQuestion4;
    @FXML
    private Button btnavancar;

    @FXML
    private void handleAvancar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        inicio.handleIniciar(event);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            carregaInfo();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QuestionarioController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QuestionarioController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void carregaInfo() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        MyConnection myConnection = new MyConnection();
        myConnection.statement = myConnection.connection.createStatement();
        Random gerador = new Random();
        int numeroGerado = gerador.nextInt(4);
        if (questionario.getNumeros().contains(numeroGerado)) {
            numeroGerado = gerador.nextInt(4);
        } else {
            questionario.setNumeros(numeroGerado);
        }

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE cod_question = " + numeroGerado;
        myConnection.result = myConnection.statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (myConnection.result.next()) {
            questionario.setDescription(myConnection.result.getString(2));
            questionario.setQuestion1(myConnection.result.getString(3));
            questionario.setQuestion2(myConnection.result.getString(4));
            questionario.setQuestion3(myConnection.result.getString(5));
            questionario.setQuestion4(myConnection.result.getString(6));
            //correct = myConnection.result.getString(7);

        }

        this.lblPergunta.setText(questionario.getDescription());
        this.rbQuestion1.setText(questionario.getQuestion1());
        this.rbQuestion2.setText(questionario.getQuestion2());
        this.rbQuestion3.setText(questionario.getQuestion3());
        this.rbQuestion4.setText(questionario.getQuestion4());
    }

}
```

O objetivo é que quando eu clique em Avançar, apareça a mesma tela, só que com perguntas diferentes. Até ai tudo bem, mas eu não quero que repita perguntas.
Estou tentando salvar os números gerados num ArrayList para ir verificando se um número já saiu ou não. Todavia ele não está adicionando os elementos na lista, está começando uma nova toda vez que chama o método.

Ao invés de [1][2][3] ele está:

[1]
[2]
[3]

Na classe Quiz (onde está o `ArrayList`) está assim:

```
public class Quiz {

    private String description;
    private String question1;
    private String question2;
    private String question3;
    private String question4;
    private String correct;
    private int qtdAcerto;
    private boolean controle = false;
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList();

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNumeros() {
        return numeros;
    }

    public void setNumeros(Integer numeros) {
        this.numeros.add(numeros);
    }

}
```

Outros getters e setters foram ocultados.

Já tentei deixar a lista nessa mesma classe de controle, e mesmo assim funcionou. Não consigo encontrar o problema de forma algum =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é todo o código? Se for altere:

```
@FXML
private void handleAvancar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    inicio.handleIniciar(event);

}
```

por:

```
@FXML
private void handleAvancar(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    carregaInfo();

}
```

E para não ficar criando uma nova instância de MyConnection substitua:

```
MyConnection myConnection = new MyConnection();
```

por

`myConnection = new MyConnection();`

e crie uma variável:

```
MyConnection myConnection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esta criando um `random` sem `seed`, e sempre cria um `new Random()`
logo, ele vai sempre gerar o mesmo número

Coloque

```
new Random(System.nanoTime())
```

Desta forma ele esta pegando o nanossegundos em que o método é executado, oque irá garintir que não seja sempre o mesmo número mesmo que você de new Random no método;

Outra forma é tirar o `random` do escopo do método, e sempre utilizar somente o `nextInt` no método.

Comment: Não funcionou. Os números estão sendo gerados corretamente e alternadamente. Problema é na hora de colocar esse número gerado no ArrayList.  Ele adiciona no array, depois que ele executa o metódo novamente, ao invés de adcionar na próxima posição, ele "reseta" o array colocando novamente na primeira posição.

Comment: Você pode colocar um construtor com um log na classe Quiz para certificar que ele esta sendo instanciado somente uma vez?